# How to programmatically find the path of a removable/mountable external memory in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

I already know of the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` method (it returns the string `/mnt/sdcard`). In the case of Samsung devices. The data goes in to the external memory but not the removable SD card. The path to that is /mnt/sdcard +/external_sd.

So does the extra subfolder vary from manufacturer to manufacturer? Is there any way we can find out the path of a removable memory device?

Comment: On the emulator and on the devices I've seen */mnt/sdcard* always referred to the root of the SD card. What happens to files you create in */mnt/sdcard* as returned by *getExternalStorageDirectory*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway we can find out the path of a removable memory device?

Not generally. Those are outside the bounds of the Android SDK at this time. The Android SDK only supports standard external storage, not anything else.

Comment: May I get the manufacture of SD card or any such hardware information about external SD card ??

Comment: @astuter: There are no APIs for that in the SDK. You might be able to get that information using whatever low-level approach you would use on Linux.